# SQL DATEDIFF return wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datetimeoffset

We want to calculate the difference between two DateTimeOffsets, however, SQL returns wrong value, what are we doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @timeInZone1 AS DATETIMEOFFSET
DECLARE @timeInZone2 AS DATETIMEOFFSET
SET @timeInZone1 = '2012-01-13 00:00:00 +1:00';
SET @timeInZone2 = '2012-01-13 23:00:00 +1:00';
SELECT DATEDIFF( day, @timeInZone1, @timeInZone2 );
```

The difference should be 0 but it returns 1

Comment: Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql): "A time zone offset component of startdate or enddate is not used in calculating the return value." I think this is documentese for "we actually calculate based on the converted UTC time" (where `2012-01-13 00:00:00 +1:00` is actually part of `2012-01-12`) rather than "we ignore time zones so the answer is at least correct when you use the same time zone consistently". Consider calculating the `hour` difference and dividing by 24 instead; this is usually what you want even without time zones.

Comment: Could it be that when you use the time '00:00:00' it is interpreted as a date only and then, according to the documentation, timezone is set to '0:00' and hence the 1 day difference.

Comment: Note that converting the `datetimeoffset` values to `datetime` does return 0: `select datediff( day, convert(datetime, @timeInZone1), convert(datetime, @timeInZone2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment if you cast it seems to work.  But not clear why to me.

```
DECLARE @timeInZone1 AS DATETIMEOFFSET
DECLARE @timeInZone2 AS DATETIMEOFFSET
SET @timeInZone1 = '2012-01-13 00:00:00 +1:00';
SET @timeInZone2 = '2012-01-13 23:00:00 +1:00';
SELECT  @timeInZone1 as z1, @timeInZone2 as z2
      , cast(@timeInZone1 as datetime) z1d,  cast(@timeInZone2 as datetime) z2d 
      , DATEDIFF(day, @timeInZone1, @timeInZone2) as diff
      , DATEDIFF(day, cast(@timeInZone1 as datetime), cast(@timeInZone2 as datetime)) as diffdt;

z1                                 z2                                 z1d                     z2d                     diff        diffdt
---------------------------------- ---------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
2012-01-13 00:00:00.0000000 +01:00 2012-01-13 23:00:00.0000000 +01:00 2012-01-13 00:00:00.000 2012-01-13 23:00:00.000 1           0
```

Comment: It's not strange- `datetime` has no offset or notion of local vs UTC. The conversion simply strips the offset. You have to use a function to take the offset into account before casting

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting! As Jeroen Mostert commented, it looks like the `datetimeoffset` values are converted to UTC:

```
select datediff(day, '2017-01-01 0:00 +1:00', '2017-01-01 1:00 +1:00') --> 1
```

Conversion to UTC would make the first value `2016-12-31 23:00', which is a day earlier.

But normal `datetime` values are not converted to UTC:

```
select datediff(day, '2017-01-01 0:00', '2017-01-01 1:00') --> 0
```

Living in UTC+1, it's surprising that adding `+1:00` gives a different result.  After all `+1:00` is the default here.